# osm2pgrouting stuck (showing classes table created) when importing an osm file

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I am trying to import an osm file using osm2pgrouting. while following the pgrouting workshop. (file is 700mb~)

im running ubuntu 12.04 on m1.large on amazon.

the same file was successfully upload to postgres with osm2pgsql.

i am using the following command:

```
osm2pgrouting -file "/home/ubuntu/israelmap/israel_and_palestine.osm"  -conf "/usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml" -dbname routing -user postgres -clean
```

the proccess starts ok, but the way table will never have any data in it:

```
We need a way of type highway and class service
We need a way of type highway and class service
We DON'T need a way of type  and class
We DON'T need a way of type  and class
We DON'T need a way of type  and class
Split ways
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "nodes_pkey" for table 

"nodes"
    Nodes table created
    NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "ways_pkey" for table "ways"
    Ways table created
    Types table created
    Classes table created
create topology
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "vertices_tmp_id_seq" for serial column "vertices_tmp.id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE vertices_tmp (id serial)"
PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 15 at EXECUTE statement
#########################
size of streets: 159747
size of splitted ways : 365597
finished
```

after a very long while (2 hrs) it sais finished but way table is empty!
how do i fix this?

- i was able to load a routing table using osm2po. still no success with osm2pgrouting

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i still have problems with that, anyone anything?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a new version of osm2pgrouting. It's available in the "[develop](https://github.com/pgrouting/osm2pgrouting/tree/develop)" branch of the Github repository or in this PPA on Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/~georepublic/+archive/pgrouting-unstable

Though this would require that you also use the new version of pgRouting.